# To understand the concept of Origin field from map_server

Tags: localization, navigation, yaml, ros-kinetic, pgm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I'm trying to run some tutorial which have a ROS Navigation Stack sample.
On doing, I couldn't understand the concept of ORIGIN field from yaml which the map_server create after mapping.

Here is a [description](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server) by ROS wiki.

> origin : The 2-D pose of the lower-left pixel in the map, as (x, y, yaw), with yaw as counterclockwise rotation (yaw=0 means no rotation). Many parts of the system currently ignore yaw.

**What this, "the lower-left pixel in the map", mean??**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322919/to-understand-the-concept-of-origin-field-from-map_server/) by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2019-05-10

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]

The red arrow in the image shows the position of the lower-left pixel. Assign a coordinate to that pixel using origin field. The coordinates of other pixels are calculated relative to the value that you had assigned to lower-left pixel.

---

Originally posted by [Veera Ragav](https://answers.ros.org/users/29301/veera-ragav/) with karma: 240 on 2019-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on 2019-07-21**:
Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Map files in pgm format can be viewed just as any image editing in tools like GIMP. See for instance also this one here:

[image: image description]

(Link taken from [Q/A 37762](https://answers.ros.org/question/37762/are-there-any-interesting-pgm-map-files-available-for-simulation/))

The origin tag in the yaml states where the bottom left pixel of this image is located relative to the map's coordinate frame (supplied via the `frame_id` [param in map_server, defaults to "map"](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/66fba702f6ac79ba9386f22d4bbc1e0f50afb5f6/map_server/src/main.cpp#L72)).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2019-05-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on 2019-05-10**:
Thanks for the answer.
Then, if I resize the size of the image file, then I need to calculate new origin field using the resolution and old origin field. right?